# получение подстроки из строки с помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

есть строка, например:
_это_та_самая_строка.окончание

с помощью какого регулярного выражения можно получить именно слово "строка?"

вариант `'/\_(.+?)\./'` возвращает "это_та_самая_строка"

```
$text = '_это_та_самая_строка.окончание';
$pattern = '/\_(.+?)\./';
preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches);
echo '<pre>';
print_r( $matches );
echo '</pre>';
```

результат

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => _это_та_самая_строка.
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => это_та_самая_строка
        )

)
```

Comment: захватывайте не подчеркивание `_([^_]+)\.`

Comment: @splash58, круто! работает. спасибо большое

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$text = '_это_та_самая_строка.окончание';
$pattern = '~.*_([а-я]+)\.~iu';

preg_match($pattern, $text, $matches);

echo $matches[1];// строка
```

Answer (score 2):

Ваше регулярное выражение находит `_` после которого в группу №1 захватываются любые символы, 1 и более раз, как можно меньше (т.к. `+?` - "ленивый" квантификатор, заставляющий движок тестировать на совпадение последующие шаблоны и возваращаться к квантифицируемому только в случае неудачи), до самого первого вхождения символа `.`. То есть `.+?` "проглатывает" все символы `_` по пути к первой точке.

Здесь несколько решений. Эдуард предлагает захватывать только 1 и более руссих букв после последнего `_` и до первой точки. Если нет уверенности, что в этом месте в строке будут только русские буквы, воспользуйтесь *исключающим символьным классом*.

```
/_([^_.]+)\./
  ^^^^^^^^
```

**Подробности**:

- `_` - символ `_`
- `([^_.]+)` - 1 и более символов, отличных от `_` и `.`
- `\.` - точка.

[PHP-демо](http://ideone.com/0vSfvF):

```
$text = '_это_та_самая_строка.окончание';
preg_match_all('/_([^_.]+)\./u', $text, $matches);
print_r( $matches[1] ); // Только содержимое первой захватывающей группы
```

Если (у некоторых возникает такое) есть желание получить массив только с желаемым результатом (т.е. избавиться от захватывающей группы), можно использовать

```
preg_match_all('/_\K[^_.]+(?=\.)/u', $text, $matches);
print_r( $matches[0] );
```

Тут `\K` удалит из текущего совпадения весь найденный до текущего момента текст, а `(?=\.)`, блок предварительного просмотра вперёд, проверит, есть ли после 1+ символов, отличных от  `.` и `_`, точка и вернёт совпадение только если точка будет найдена.

Comment: спасибо большое! очень доходчиво